# Preserving Language across inline Calculated Members in SSAS

Tags: globalization, mdx, ssas

Problem: I need to retrieve the language of a given cell from the cube. The cell is defined by code-generated MDX, which can have an arbitrary level of indirection as far as calculated members and sets go (defined in the `WITH` clause). SSAS appears to ignore the Language of the specified members when you declare a calculated member inline in the query.

Example:

- The cube's default locale is 1033 (en-US)
- The cube contains a Calculated Measure called `[Net Pounds]` which is defined as `[Net Amt], language=2057` (en-GB)
- The query requests this measure alongside an inline calculated measure which is simply an alias to the `[Net Pounds]`
- When used directly, the measure is formatted in the en-GB locale, but when aliased, the measure falls back to using the cube default of en-US.

Here's what the query looks like:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Pounds Indirect] AS [Measures].[Net Pounds]
SELECT { [Measures].[Pounds Indirect], [Measures].[Net Pounds] } ON AXIS (0)
FROM [Cube] CELL PROPERTIES language, value, formatted_value
```

The query returns the expected two cells, but only uses the `[Net Pounds]` locale when used directly.

Is there an option or switch somewhere in SSAS that will allow locale information to be visible in calculated members? I realise that it is possible to declare the inline calculated member in a particular locale, but this would involve extracting the locale from the tuple first, which (since the cube's member is isolated in the application's query schema) is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's no good solution here. When declaring a calculated member in the query, the locale must be specified, otherwise it is defaulted to the cube's locale. Them's the rules, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

WITH

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Category] AS [Dim Category].[Category Parent ID].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("LCID1036")
MEMBER [Measures].[Survey Date] AS [Dim Survey Date].[Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("LCID1036")

SELECT 
NON EMPTY{[Measures].[AVG MFA Score], [Measures].[CategoryIsLeaf], [Measures].[Category], [Measures].[Survey Date]} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { filter((DESCENDANTS(STRTOSET("[Dim Survey Date].[Hierarchy].members"),[Dim Survey Date].[Hierarchy].[Month],SELF), STRTOSET("[Dim Category].[Category Parent ID].members")),[Measures].[AVG MFA Score]<>null)}

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
from [MFA DWH]
```

Comment: That's some mighty-fine MDX you got there, but I can't figure out quite how that applies the LCID of the source member to the target member. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the locale information is only available if the translation has the caption column bound to the data source, is this the case for your example?

Comment: I built my demonstration using a pre-built cube which is used primarily for training users of our own software. I edited it using BIDS to add an extra calculated measure which has its `Language` property explicitly set. The problem here is not with building the cube or pulling data into it, but with preserving this language information when querying with inline calculated measures.